# change max Buffer Length in MPEG-dash format

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, video.js, mpeg-dash, clappr

I'm trying to change the max buffer length on my video streaming in clappr video player.
I know that in HLS format the way to do it is like this:

```
player = new Clappr.Player({
      playback: {
        hlsjsConfig: {
         maxMaxBufferLength: 30
      }}})
```

And it's realy working for HLS videos,
I'm looking for equivalent way to do it with MPEG-dash foramt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you playing DASH in Clappr?

If you are using Shaka, https://github.com/clappr/dash-shaka-playback, set it up as shown at https://github.com/clappr/dash-shaka-playback, using the buffer settings you require as described at https://github.com/google/shaka-player/blob/master/docs/tutorials/network-and-buffering-config.md#buffering-configuration

Eg:

```
player = new Clappr.Player({
  source: '//storage.googleapis.com/shaka-demo-assets/angel-one/dash.mpd',
  plugins: [DashShakaPlayback],
  shakaConfiguration: {
    preferredAudioLanguage: 'pt-BR',
    streaming: {
      bufferingGoal: 30,
      rebufferingGoal: 15,
      bufferBehind: 60
    }
  }
});
```